# Orbeon put own control in form builder controls panel

Tags: forms, orbeon, xbl

I want to write own control and put it in the controls panel in form builder. But firstly, for training, I want to put some example control like 'tutorial-davinci' to form builder. How Can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add your own Toolbox Group via [properties](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-builder#TOC-Control-groups).
- The property contains a list of references to XBL files. Note that your XBL must have some [metadata](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/user-guide/form-builder-user-guide/toolbox-component-metadata).